# ARRAYFORMULA summing column with previous recursively for all columns

Tags: google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

Let's say my formula is in D2. I want to sum the value from previous column with another sheet column and do it for all rows, I can do the following:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(C2:C+AnotherSheet!D2:D)
```

Now I would like the next column to do the same:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(D2:D+AnotherSheet!E2:E)
```

How would I set it up, so it works for all columns without manually copy pasting this formula to the next column.

Answer (score 0):

This quick and dirty brute force formula might be some help, depending on how many columns you need.  Try this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({C2:C+Sheet2!D2:D,
               C2:C+Sheet2!D2:D+Sheet2!E2:E,
               C2:C+Sheet2!D2:D+Sheet2!E2:E+Sheet2!F2:F,
               C2:C+Sheet2!D2:D+Sheet2!E2:E+Sheet2!F2:F+Sheet2!G2:G,
               C2:C+Sheet2!D2:D+Sheet2!E2:E+Sheet2!F2:F+Sheet2!G2:G+Sheet2!H2:H})
```

It wouldn't be too hard to automatically generate the full formula you need, if your number of columns isn't changing all the time.

But I imagine someone will come up with an elegant formula to somehow do the same thing.  Let us know if this helps.

[image]